Problem 4 chapter 1 Landau's mechanics
I don't understand how the apparatus works. In particular whether the angle $\theta$ is changing as $m_2$ moves vertically. Taking A as the origin of the system, the initial distance of $m_2$ is $l_2 = 2a \cos \theta$.
The text writes $dl_2 = -2a \sin \theta d\theta$, this means that $\theta$ is varying. If so, How Does it do it? Is it $m_2$ stretching and elongating the arms of the apparatus as it moves vertically?

https://media.cheggcdn.com/media/e22/e22a7a87-7701-46e2-ac63-6eea15faedd0/phpcUBIHw

Sometimes mathematical, geometric and graphic abstraction obscures the obviuus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_governor.

can the mass $m_2$ move till point $A$? and in doing so are the arms stretched?

are the arms stretched --- The 4 side lengths are constant, as the planar figure is a rhombus whose side lengths are fixed. The sides can rotate about the vertices due to links/hinges (not sure of the correct word or term) at the vertices, as indicated in some of these examples.

Mass is located at
$$
\cases{
p_1 = a(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta,0)\\
p_2 = a(0,-2\cos\theta,0)
}
$$
the velocities are
$$
\cases{
\vec v_1=a(\dot \theta\cos\theta,\dot\theta\sin\theta, \Omega\sin\theta)\\
\vec v_2 = \dot p_2
}
$$
and the Lagrangian is
$$
L = \frac 12(2m_1\|\vec v_1\|^2)+\frac 12m_2\|\vec v_2\|^2-2m_1 g p_1\cdot \hat e_y-m_2 g p_2\cdot \hat e_y
$$
here $\hat e_y = (0,1,0)$

I don't understand how the distance traveled by $m_2$ depends only on $\theta$

$m_2$ moves along the rotation axis.

so you only need the degree of freedom $\theta$ to describe the motion of $m_2$

Yes. This is the point.

but how does the term $2gam_2 \cos \theta$ appears there?

The rotation has angular velocity $\Omega$.

Think of a mechanism contained in the plane $(x,y)$ with $y$ meaning the vertical, and rotating around the vertical axis with angular velocity $\Omega$. The gravity acts along the vertical axis and the Lagrangian is $L = T-V$.
